# Avoid hex-encoding in a text-file for a searching program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a python program to analyze a server log(a text file) and to find non matching strings to a user input. Anyway hex-encoded strings are not considered by the program.
Ex : In the following case the program says that there are no non-matching values to the user input although 'www.peoplesmonton.com' is available. Please help me to avoid this?

```
for line in lines:
    match = re.search('\\b' + userinput + '\\b',line)
```

sample text file:

```
https://www.mysite.com/myworks/accaply/inquiry.asp 
http://www.peoplesmonton.com/amb/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt%20Bank%20Of%20Frnak%20PLC_asp.htm 
http://www.peoplesmonton.com/comblk/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt%20Bank%20Of%20ambt%20PLC_asp.htm
```

Comment: suppose the user input is 'www.mysite.com' which i have forgotten to write the question.

Answer (score 2):

The information is *URL encoded*, so use `urllib2.unquote` to decode that.

```
>>> input = '''\
... https://www.mysite.com/myworks/accaply/inquiry.asp 
... http://www.peoplesmonton.com/amb/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt%20Bank%20Of%20Frnak%20PLC_asp.htm 
... http://www.peoplesmonton.com/comblk/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt%20Bank%20Of%20ambt%20PLC_asp.htm 
... '''
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.unquote(input)
https://www.mysite.com/myworks/accaply/inquiry.asp 
http://www.peoplesmonton.com/amb/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt Bank Of Frnak PLC_asp.htm 
http://www.peoplesmonton.com/comblk/cgi-bin/bank/bank/ambt Bank Of ambt PLC_asp.htm
```

Comment: Congrats on almost 100k, gaining rep faster than John Skeet ;)